# How do I calculate the probability of a short option position expiring worthless?

Tags: options, greeks, expiration

I want to be able to determine the probability of a short option position (call or put) expiring worthless.

Don't know where to start but I see probabilities derived from the greeks on some web sites?

Comment: Are you familiar with $N(d_2)$ ? see http://www.ltnielsen.com/wp-content/uploads/Understanding.pdf

Comment: Can you calculate arbitrary priced options? If so just Calc. The price of a digital at the same strike.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

As I have often heard this theory of "delta == probability of being ITM", I just put on some wise words from Paul Wilmott ;)

Comment: Agreed. Although one could argue that it *is* the probability of the option being ITM. But under a probability measure using the underlying asset price as numéraire, which although being mathematically equivalent to the real world measure, is a pure mathematical construct,  hence not very useful.

Answer (score 1):

You can think of delta for calls (-delta for puts) as the first order approximation to probability of expiring in the money. If you subtract this probability from 100%, you'll have the probability of expiring worthless.

If you want more exact probability, there are algorithms to construct a pdf from IV skew, and calculate probability from there.